# ControllerContext is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this MVC4 controller (`ControllerB`):

```
public class MyControllerB : Controller
{
    public bool Check(string actionName, ControllerBase controllerBase)
    {
        ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, controllerBase);

        ...
    }
}
```

I'm calling ControllerB's Check method from "ControllerA", like so:

```
bool b = new MyControllerB().Check("Index", this);
```

I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` because `this.ControllerContext` is null.

If I move the Check method to ControllerA, it works just fine. But I need this method to be in a different controller. How can I fix my code so that ``this.ControllerContext` will not be null?

Comment: have you tried making the method static in controller b so you don't have to instantiate the controller?

Comment: Why would you need to call the method from different controller, maybe create a BaseController and put your method there?

Comment: @DZL: How's that going to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The `ControllerContext` is null because you are manually creating the `ControllerB` instance from `ControllerA`.

Normally, `IController` instances are created by the registered `IControllerFactory`, typically `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory`. The controller factory will `new()` the instance and initialize settings properly.

As @DZL says, it is normally much better to have both controllers subclass a `BaseController` class, which can have shared initialization and shared properties and methods.

I don't understand the business logic of what you are trying to do, but here's a code example of using the base class from the 2 controllers:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class MyControllerBase : Controller
    {
        public bool Check(string actionName, ControllerBase controllerBase)
        {
            ControllerContext controllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.ControllerContext.RequestContext, controllerBase);
            return false;
        }
    }
    public class MyControllerA : MyControllerBase
    {
        ActionResult Index()
        {
            bool b = base.Check("Index", this);
            return View();
        }
    }
    public class MyControllerB : MyControllerBase
    {
        ActionResult Index()
        {
            bool b = base.Check("Index", this);
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

If you really want to do exactly what you are asking, you'll have to call `IControllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName)` instead of `new ControllerB()`, but that is a really convoluted way of doing things - I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Found the answer here: [http://forums.asp.net/t/1409129.aspx](http://forums.asp.net/t/1409129.aspx)
Don't know if this is the most efficient way... and I don't know of another way at this point.
Any ideas?